# How to save a encoded image using Pickle

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, pickle, opencv3.0

What I am doing here is encoding a image and then adding this into a list with the path of the original image in the database variable like this

```
database.append[path, encoding]
```

I then want to save this database variable into a pickle for use in other programs. how would I go about doing that as I have had no luck with saving the files correctly yet. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the method that I am using to generate the variables I want to save

```
def embedDatabase(imagePath, model, metadata):
#Get the metadata


#Perform embedding
# calculated by feeding the aligned and scaled images into the pre-trained network.

'''
#Go through the database and get the embedding for each image
'''
database = []
embedded = np.zeros((metadata.shape[0], 128))
print("Embedding")
for i, m in enumerate(metadata):
    img = imgUtil.loadImage(m.image_path())
    _,img = imgUtil.alignImage(img)
     # scale RGB values to interval [0,1]
    if img is not None:
        img = (img / 255.).astype(np.float32)
        #Get the embedding vectors for the image
        embedded[i] = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0))[0]
        database.append([m.image_path(), embedded[i]])

#return the array of embedded images from the database    
return embedded, database
```

And this is the load image method

```
def loadImage(path):
img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
if img is not None:  
    # OpenCV loads images with color channels
    # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
    return img[...,::-1]
else:
    pass
    print("There is no Image avaliable")
```

Comment: I'm confused. I can't see a question. And the title talks about Pickle but there's no Pickle-related code. And the question says you want to save a database that isn't a database. Please click `edit` under your question and clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: Ok i redid it hope this clarifies what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
with open("database.pickle", "wb") as f:
     pickle.dump(database, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

for some reason I needed the pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL Thing